# C++/QT - Converting data to different format via QByteArray differs from reading into struct

Tags: c++, qt, types

I am attempting to read in a header. Here is the structure:

```
struct header
{
    uint32 offset;
    char identifier[4];
    uint32 unknown;
};
```

When I read copy the memory in via memcpy, I can output the offset correctly (usually as a large number).

When using built in function with the byte array, I read in the whole file and then take the first four bytes by using:

```
QByteArray offset = data.left(4);
```

I then verified that it had copied correctly, which it had.

My problem is when it comes to converting these bytes to the appropriate datatype. I have tried:

```
 qDebug() << "Offset1:" << offset.toUShort();
    qDebug() << "Offset2:" << offset;
    qDebug() << "Offset3:" << offset.toHex();
    qDebug() << "Offset4:" << offset.toInt();
    qDebug() << "Offset5:" << offset.toLong();
    qDebug() << "Offset6:" << offset.toUInt();
    qDebug() << "Offset7:" << offset.toULong();
    qDebug() << "Offset8:" << offset.toULongLong();
    qDebug() << "Offset9:" << offset.toULong();
```

None of them output the correct value. On the other hand, when I just memcpy and then use:

```
qDebug() << "Offset:" << header.offset;
```

I get the correct value. What am I missing in the conversion from the bytes to uint32?

Does it have to do with the endianness?

Comment: Don't you need to change the base? `bool ok; offset.toInt(&ok, 16);`

Comment: That'd work for "FF", but not for 0xFF

Answer (score 3):

toInt() etc. convert string repesentations like "100" to integer, not binary representations. 
To convert the binary back, you must cast it:

```
 const quint32 v = *reinterpret_cast<const quint32*>( offset.constData() );
```

Note that this is fragile due to endianness. memcpy with structs is also not safely portable due to struct alignment (padding). Better use [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdatastream.html) or something like [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) or [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) for more robust serialization.